# Rails hit new method on save of simpleform

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this method

```
def create
    @newevent = Event.new(create_params)
    @newevent.save!
    flash[:success] = "Event Created"
    redirect_to "/events"
  end
```

And this form

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Editing event:
  <%= @newevent.id %></h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= simple_form_for @newevent do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventname %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventname, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :event_type, :collection => ['Concert','Festival','Sports','Theatre'] %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventdesc %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventdesc, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventshortdesc %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventshortdesc, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :pagetitle %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :pagetitle, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :metatag %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :metatag, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventvenuename %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventvenuename, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :time, type: "time", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.input :date, type: "date", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :eventimage %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.text_field :eventimage, :autofocus => true, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.check_box :eventready %>
          <%= f.label :eventready, "Is event ready for SEO?" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <%= f.check_box :eventcomplete %>
          <%= f.label :eventcomplete, "Is event ready for Public?" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-info" %>
<%= link_to "Delete", event_path(@newevent), :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm currently populating this form with the edit method here

```
  def edit
    @newevent = Master.find(params[:id])
  end
```

How can i go about making this pull in information from the Master table to auto populate the table but then save to the Event table?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple update method?

```
def update
  @newevent = Event.find(params[:id])

  if @newevent.update_attributes(params[:newevent])
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

Comment: Only issue with this is its not using anything to do with the Master table in your example (Its been a super long day and i probably should know this!)

Comment: It's loading from `Master` and saving to `Event`, isn't that what you want?